# How to Post a .json file to ArangoDB using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, arangodb

I am trying to post a .json file as a single document to an ArangoDB collection, from within javascript/ajax.

I can post (to ArangoDB) the .json file using curl, so that works
I can post (to ArangoDB) simple {key: value} pairs using AJAX, so that works, but combining the two seems to be a bridge too far.  I have spent a couple of nights trying to get this far, so any help would be hugely appreciated.  thanks in advance.

My javascript code looks like this

```
var database_URL = prompt("Please enter your  URL", "http://xxx..xxx.xxxx.:8529/_db/collection_name/_api/document?collection=PA_Users&createCollection=false");

    var fd = new FormData();
    var selectedFile = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
    console.log(selectedFile.name);// this works
    fd.append(selectedFile.name,selectedFile);

var settings = {
      url : database_URL,
      type : "POST",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(username1 + ":" + passwrd1)
      },
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
      // display feedback to user
      alert("booyah");
    },
      error: function(data) {
          // display feedback to user
          alert("boo hoo");
        }
  };

  $.ajax(settings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use /_api/import instead of /_api/document:

[HTTP Interface for Bulk Imports](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpBulkImports/index.html)

Here is a small working example (without authorization):

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:
        '/_api/import?type=auto&collection=' + 
                encodeURIComponent(yourCollectionID) +
        '&createCollection=false',
      data: file,
      processData: false,
      contentType: 'json',
      dataType: 'json',
      complete: function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 201) {
          callback(false);
        } else {
          try {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (data.errors > 0) {
              // error
            }
            else {
              // success 
            }
          }
          catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

The api supports a few input formats:

1.) Single document

```
{name: "Jonny"}
```

2.) Multiple documents (one doc in each row)

```
{name: "Jonny"}
{name: "Adam"}
{name: "Peter"}
```

3.) Multiple documents in JSON array

```
[{name: "Jonny"}, {name: "Adam"}, {name: "Peter"}]
```

Comment: thank you, the switch from the document api to the import api made all the difference, and my code is working now.  Danke, Grazie.

Comment: sorry for the delay in marking accepted, this was my first post, and I had to find the accept button.  thanks again